# Postgres select into from string list

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, plpgsql

I have list of strings:
`var ids = ["aa", "cc, "bb"];`

and I want to insert them into temporary table. This is how I try to do it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ids;
CREATE TEMP TABLE Ids AS
SELECT Id FROM @ids
```

however that throws syntax error. How it should be done?

Comment: What kind of error? Please, provide error details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is an array, so the query should use array functions

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE Ids AS
SELECT unnest(ARRAY['a','b','c']);
```

or using the .net place holder:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE Ids AS
SELECT unnest(@ids);
```